# Proving that the given piecewise function is not monotonic, but invertible

Tags: functions

The piecewise function is $f(x)$=\begin{cases}
x, x \in \mathbb{Q} &\\
-x, x\in \mathbb{I}
\end{cases}
I have to prove that this function is not monotonic in any interval and that it's invertible.
I watched a lot of videos on youtube to understand this problem, and I thought if I can prove that this function is bijective, then it has to be invertible, but I don't know how I can prove that either.
And for monotonicity I tried proving some special cases, I don't think that's considered a formal proof.
Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $\mathbb{I}$?

Comment: @Guenterino irrational numbers...I'm sorry if that's confusing I'm just really bad at MathJax

Comment: Ah ok sorry. No it's not confusing. I just have never seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(f(x))=x$, i.e., $f$ is its own inverse and so is invertible.

Assume $f$ is monotonic in some interval $(a,b)$. By density of rationals, there exist rational numbers $a<x_1<x_2<b$, for which $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, i.e., $f$ is *not* weakly decreasing on $(a,b)$. Likewise, by densitiy of irrationals, there exist irrational numbers $a<y_1<y_2<b$, for which $f(y_1)>f(y_2)$, i.e., $f$ is *not* weakly increasing on $(a,b)$, either.

Comment: And how do you compute $f(f(x))$ here?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the given function as $f(x)$.

Consider a real number $y$, if it is rational then $f(y) = y$ and if it is irrational then $f(-y) = y$ so $f$ is onto. Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$ for some real $x$ and $y$, then we claim that $x=y$. Obviously we cannot have one is rational and other one is irrational, so we must have both of them is rational or both of them is irrational. Hence $f(x) = f(y)  \implies x = y $ or $-x = -y$ and we are done showing $f$ is bijective.